# Caret in objective C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

What does the caret in objective C mean?

ie.

`void (^handler)(NSInteger);`

from [Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/QuickStart/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH22-SW5)

Comment: It's also worth noting that Blocks are a C extension added by Apple according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)).

Comment: It is similar to lambda in Lisp or Python

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It depends on the context. In the example you show, it's used to denote a Block. The caret symbol is also the [bitwise XOR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) in C-based languages — that's what most programmers would identify it as, so it's good to understand that it can be both depending on where it appears, much like `*`, etc.

And while we're suggesting references, one simply has to include [Apple's official Blocks reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/).

Answer (score 15):

The caret represents a block or a closure which carries around or contains the lexical scope.  They are similar to blocks in ruby. An excellent reference can be found [here](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#whatareblocks).

Comment: Could you give any more detail?

Comment: added a reference above that should get you started

Answer (score 4):

Like ennuikiller said, it indicates a block. If you want to learn more, Ars Technica had an excellent in-depth [review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6.ars/10) of Snow Leopard that described not only blocks and closures, but also Grand Central Dispatch and all the other new technologies in Mac OS X 10.6. Highly recommended.