# Use of the '^' symbol in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, function, syntax

I have noticed that in a lot of code functions can be defined inside the code to be some sort of callback method. That function can be defined using the ^ symbol. Can anyone clarify how to use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1). They're essentially anonymous functions like you have in JavaScript with the `function(){}` syntax (and like in JavaScript, they are [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))).

Answer (score 1):

Those are blocks.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html