# What does the symbol ^ mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caret in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c)

I just want to know what this ^ symbol means in Objective-C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c - says it all.

Comment: @DaveRandom: You were 3 seconds ahead of me.

Comment: @hari lol, isn't Google a wonderful tool if you know what to look for, and I love the fact that it usually directs me straight back to SO...

Answer (score 5):

It can mean several things:

```
type (^name)(arguments)
```

is a declaration of a block object.

```
^(arguments) { ... }
```

is a block object literal

```
x ^ y
```

is the bitwise XOR operator

Answer (score 0):

It is used to define blocks in later versions of iOS. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

It means a couple of things:

1. It can mean bitwise `XOR`.
2. It can also signify a pointer to a block (just like `*` is marks a pointer to a function).