# what does the ^ symbol mean in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caret in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c)

what does the ^ symbol mean in objective-C?

code:

```
 GreeRequestServicePopup* requestPopup = [GreeRequestServicePopup popup];
 requestPopup.parameters = parameters;

 requestPopup.willLaunchBlock = ^(id aSender) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"request_service_popup_will_launch_block" object:nil];

 };

 requestPopup.didLaunchBlock = ^(id aSender) {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"request_service_popup_did_launch_block" object:nil];
 };

 requestPopup.willDismissBlock = ^(id aSender) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"request_service_popup_will_dismiss_block" object:nil];
 };

 requestPopup.didDismissBlock = ^(id aSender) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"request_service_popup_did_dismiss_block" object:nil];
 };

 requestPopup.cancelBlock = ^(id aSender) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"request_service_popup_cancel_block" object:nil];
 };

 requestPopup.completeBlock = ^(id aSender) {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"request_service_popup_complete_block" object:nil];
 };

 [self.navigationController showGreePopup:requestPopup];
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: block literal. for every block, there is a non-block way of doing it, pretty much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c

Answer (score 5):

`^` is a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) literal.  The block literal is followed by arguments, and then curly braces to indicate the actual meat of the code:

```
| ^          | (id arg)    | {};          |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| Block      | Parameters  |     Body     |
| literal    |             |              |
```

Block literals are explained fairly well [here](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1/).

Answer (score 3):

`^` signifies a **block**. See more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Practically, this specifies a piece of code that will be executed at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

Those are Blocks. You can read a good introduction [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html). Then read [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502) for more details.