# What does ^ mean in objective c ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

Sorry to ask such a simple question but these things are hard to Google.

I have code in iOS which is connected to toggle which is switching between Celsius and Fahrenheit and I don't know what ^ 1 means. self.celsius is Boolean

Thanks

```
self.celsius = self.celsius ^ 1;
```

Comment: It refers to a bitwise XOR operator.

Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c

Comment: Hint:  When you're stuck on such an issue don't Google for Objective-C, just Google for "C" (plus, of course, other appropriate terms, such as "operators").

Comment: why would you do this instead of `self.celsius = ! self.celsius` it's just confusing right?

Comment: The link did answer my question, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a C-language operator meaning "Bitwise Exclusive OR".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) gives a good explanation:

**XOR**

> A bitwise XOR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the
>   logical exclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The
>   result in each position is 1 if only the first bit is 1 or only the
>   second bit is 1, but will be 0 if both are 0 or both are 1. In this we
>   perform the comparison of two bits, being 1 if the two bits are
>   different, and 0 if they are the same. For example:

```
    0101 (decimal 5)
XOR 0011 (decimal 3)
  = 0110 (decimal 6)
```

> The bitwise XOR may be used to invert selected bits in a register
>   (also called toggle or flip). Any bit may be toggled by XORing it with
>   1. For example, given the bit pattern 0010 (decimal 2) the second and fourth bits may be toggled by a bitwise XOR with a bit pattern
>   containing 1 in the second and fourth positions:

```
    0010 (decimal 2)
XOR 1010 (decimal 10)
  = 1000 (decimal 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the bitwise XOR operator (see http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#Bitwise_XOR).

What it's doing in this case is switching back and forth, because `0 ^ 1` is 1, and `1 ^ 1` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's an exclusive OR operation.