# Understanding "Carat" functions in C?

Tags: c, function, literals

I asked other programmers, and they said that carat `^` means xor. But it seems there is an obscure use of carat that I don't fully understand. It seems that `^` suffixing a type modifies it in some way, like how suffixing a type with `*` declares it a pointer type. The code below works, but can someone explain why and what is going on, and how the carat symbol allows me to declare anonymous function literals inline? I didn't know that you could do that, but I want to fully understand this mysterious functionality.

```
void(^Function)(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Function = ^{
        int x = 10;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    };
    Function();
    Function = ^{
        putchar(65);
    };
    Function();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, is this some compiler extension or is this pure C?

[image]

Comment: This is not `C` language. Based on output from https://www.onlinegdb.com/.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко I am compiling on code runner on mac

Comment: @ЯрославМашко: It is C. It is not strictly conforming C. Per the C standard, a *conforming program* is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation, and a conforming implementation is one that accepts any *strictly conforming program*. In other words, a conforming implementation may have extensions, and a C program that uses such extensions is a conforming C program (if it does not otherwise violate C constraints).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caret in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Apple extension to C called [Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1), for [Grand Central Dispatch](https://web.archive.org/web/20090920043909/http://images.apple.com/macosx/technology/docs/GrandCentral_TB_brief_20090903.pdf).

Comment: @0x10: Blocks is a compiler extension, not directly an operating system feature. It is available in Clang, as shown by this [Godbolt sample](https://godbolt.org) and the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#blocks). I do not see that it is in GCC outside of Apple’s version.

Comment: Is there a cross platform version?

Comment: @0x10: Clang supports a number of targets. It is a compiler you may use instead of GCC.